# MRJob Sort in Python

Tags: python, sorting, mapreduce

I have an assignment that requires me to use mapper/reducer in python to complete a MapReduce for customer data. I have a CSV file with the CustomerID, ProductID, and the Amount Spent. The first task is to determine for each customer the total spent, which I easily completed. The next part requires me to take this list and sort by the total amount spent in descending order. I am struggling here... the recommendation was to use a MapReduce on top of another MapReduce. Here are my codes:

## PART 1:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class TotalAmountCust(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        (customerid, idno, amount) = line.split(',')
        yield customerid, float(amount)

    def reducer(self, customerid, amount):
        yield customerid, sum(amount)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TotalAmountCust.run()
```

## PART 2:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class TotalAmountCustSort(MRJob):
    def steps(self):
        return [ MRStep(mapper = self.map_by, reducer = self.red_by),
                MRStep(mapper = self.map_sort, reducer = self.red_sort) ]
    def map_by(self, _, line):
        (customerid, idno, amount) = line.split(',')
        yield customerid.zfill(2), float(amount)
    def red_by(self, customerid, amount):
        yield customerid, '%04.02f' % sum(amount)
    def map_sort(self, customerid, total):
        yield float(total), customerid
    def red_sort(self, total, customerid):
        yield total, customerid
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TotalAmountCustSort.run()
```

Part 2 has a problem and will not give me a result at all. Any advice would be well recommended... I attempted research on MRJob.SORT_VALUES = True but that did not give me the results I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

I solved, output is ordered now

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class SpendByCustomerSorted(MRJob):

    MRJob.SORT_VALUES = True

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_get_orders,
                   reducer=self.reducer_totals_by_customer),
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_make_amounts_key,
                   reducer=self.reducer_output_results_for_single_reducer)
        ]
    def mapper_get_orders(self, _, line):
        (customerID, itemID, orderAmount) = line.split(',')
        yield customerID, float(orderAmount)

    def reducer_totals_by_customer(self, customerID, orders):
        yield customerID, sum(orders)

    def mapper_make_amounts_key(self, customerID, orderTotal):
        yield None, ("%07.02f"%float(orderTotal), customerID)

    def reducer_output_results(self, n, orderTotalCustomerIDs):
        for c in orderTotalCustomerIDs:
            yield c[1], c[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SpendByCustomerSorted.run()
```